# Waiting for storyboard animation to finish before changing view in Silverlight 4 using MVVM

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm

I have a login page in Silverlight 4. I am using MVVM to handle all interactions with the page. On successful login I have a custom event that fires in my view model followed by code to navigate to the main page. I use event aggregation, publish & subscribe for navigating between views.

```
 AnimateLoginSuccess(this, null);
//code to navigate to the main page after successful login.
```

I handle this event in my view, wiring it up like this, where LoginSuccessStoryboard is the storyboard I have created for some basic animation:

```
    //constructor of view
    public Login(LoginVM vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = vm;
        thisVM = vm;

        vm.AnimateLoginSuccess += new EventHandler(vm_AnimateLoginSuccess);

    }


//event handling method in view
    void vm_AnimateLoginSuccess(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoginSuccessStoryboard.Begin();
    }
```

**Now**, the problem is, even though the animation begins after successful login, the next lines that handle moving to a different view on successful login make the moving to the next view so fast that it doesn't wait for the animation to finish. Thereby making the animation virtually non-existant. Any ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [Completed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.completed%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) event of your Storyboard, to navigate to your view after the animation has ended. Add a method to your ViewModel, that gets executed after the animation to navigate to the default first view.

```
public Login(LoginVM vm) {
    InitializeComponent();

    LoginSuccessStoryboard.Completed += new EventHandler(NavigateToViewAfterAnimation);
    DataContext = vm;
    thisVM = vm;

    vm.AnimateLoginSuccess += new EventHandler(vm_AnimateLoginSuccess);

}

private void NavigateToViewAfterAnimation(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   thisVW.NavigateToFirstView();  // Navigates to the first view.
}
```